# Не работает Node.js в VS CODE, Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, fedora, gnome

Поставил Fedora Linux 37.
Установил vs code.
Установил через терминал node и npm (в терминале если прописать команды node -version и npm -version, всё срабатывает).
В vs code команды npm и node не срабатывают.
Добавил в path ноду, менял терминалы в самом vs code но не работает.
как исправить?

Добавил в path ноду, менял терминалы в самом vs code но не работает.
как исправить?

[image]

Comment: Проверьте есть ли nodejs в PATH именно в терминале VSCode, а также попробуйте полный путь прописать к nodejs.